# Use alpha or opacity on a table row using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS stylesheet for a webpage. The webpage has a table with a background color of white (set in the rows, not the table). I would like to set the opacity or alpha to 50%. I have tried so many variations, but come up with no luck.

A typical row in the HTML file is:

```
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Twitter</td>
</tr>
```

The CSS settings for table rows (which works perfectly) is:

```
tr {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background:rgb(255,255,255);  
}
```

To get the alpha, I tried

```
tr {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);  
    }
```

I have also tried `background-color-opacity: 0.5`;

Any other suggestions?

Comment: opacity of what, table? do you want table to be partial see through?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, all browser do not support it in the same way! To get your desired result at FF, Opera, Chrome etc you can use the following 2 lines of CSS:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
```

[THIS](http://css3generator.com/) link is also helpful to get various types of CSS3 codes.

I am afraid if you want to work alpha property work at IE, then for different version(s) you have to use different types codes. You can google it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css3%20alpha%20with%20ie).

Hope it helps you! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tr {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

OR

```
table {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

You can see a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/qE2RV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a live example we can look at or a JSFiddle that can reproduce the problem?

Here is a proof of concept showing that your CSS should work: http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/VVA6q/

You are likely getting a conflict from some other CSS

Answer (score 1):

If you want table to be see through, http://jsfiddle.net/YyNmG/

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Twitter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Twitter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Twitter</td>
</tr>
</table>​
```

CSS

```
table{
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.4);
}
body{
    background-color:red;
}​
```

if only TRs, http://jsfiddle.net/YyNmG/1/

```
tr{
    background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.4);
}
table{background-color:black;}
body{
    background-color:red;
}
```